# Copy all files and folders from some root

Tags: python

In python, is there an easy method for copying all files and folders from some root to some destination root?  Creating all non-existent directories along the way, of course..

*edit* how does this change if the root destination directory already exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[distutils.dir_util.copy_tree](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree)

Comment: Cool, thanks!  What happens if a file already exists?  Does it get overwritten?

Comment: heads up needs 2.7.5 Absent from 2.7.2

Answer (score 3):

[`shutil.copytree(src, dst[, symlinks=False[, ignore=None]])`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

Comment: Thanks!  The problem with this method is that if the destination directory exists, this fails.  What if I want to copy several folders of files into /some/folder/here ?

Comment: Then I guess @Pratik Deoghare will fit better :)

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html

There are some functions there which you can use, like `copytree`